# Liquid layout in XUL

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, label, xul

I would like to use something like "float:left" css on  inside  with specified width to create multiline layout instead of using rows, is there a way to do that?

Example:

```xml
<box style="max-width:200px;" >
<label width="100px" value="1" />
<label width="100px" value="2" />
<label width="100px" value="3" />
<label width="100px" value="4" />
</box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `<box>` with `<description>` that should do it. Remember that there is also padding and margin so the above example will most likely only have 1 entry per line.